# Can VBA Arrays store cell properties like Font Colors or Fill Colors?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

The screenshot below shows that dates filled are highlighted with different colors and I need to add more to flag different issues from the installation process.

[image: img]

I have to calculate productivity and account for the installation issues in the calculation. The only way for me to identify the issues is by assigning different fill colors/font colors.

If I pass this range of data in a variant array, **will I be able to refer font/fill color properties** or is there an indirect way to refer to the cell address from the array?

Comment: Short answer: no.  Longer answer: the only way to get a cells format properties is to loop the range and access them cell by cell.  This is why using format to contain data is a bad idea

Comment: As chris stated, variables (including arrays) store data.  You could create an array complex enough to store values as well as formatting information, but each format property is just another piece of data.  Formatting is not automatically stored with numbers. But, whatever you're trying to do can likely be accomplished in a more logical way.  I think your mistake is your assumption that it is the `only way for me to identify the issues`.  There are numerous ways to identify/track issues, other than via formatting.  If you're using Conditional Formatting then that should be clarified in the Q.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I will look into ways in which I can implement my flags in this data set.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @chris neilsen , but... I just realized that You can implement to your `Array` 3rd dimension, which can hold, for example, color property.

I checked that. Even on small amount of data it is faster than standard approach to this issue!

Let's show it on example code: (worksheet structure) in first row are headers, in first column we got ID of products.
So first of all we need to declare and build our `Array` (called `zakres`) with cells value and color property.

```
Sub main1()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim comper As Range
Dim j1 As Long
Dim i As Long

Dim zakres As Variant 'our 3 dimension Array

Set ws = Sheet1 'set your worksheet

With ws
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ReDim zakres(1 To lastRow, 1 To lastCol, 1 To 2)

    For i = 1 To lastRow

        For j1 = 1 To lastCol

            zakres(i, j1, 1) = .Cells(i, j1)                        'cells value
            zakres(i, j1, 2) = .Cells(i, j1).Interior.ColorIndex    'cells color property

        Next

    Next
```

After all things we want to do on that table - I mean Array `zakres` - just paste all the values to your worksheet, using double loop (rows and columns)

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
    For j1 = 1 To lastCol
        .Cells(i, j1) = zakres(i, j1, 1)
        .Cells(i, j1).Interior.Color = zakres(i, j1, 2)
    Next
Next
```

I made that modification to my code, which is using only 1 property of cell - color property - and that approach accelerates my code a lot.

Ps. If You don't want to fill `Array` with empty cells just make condition functions in loops, which will skip iterations for empties. It will also help and speed up macro.

```
    If .Cells(i, j1) <> "" Then
        zakres(i, j1, 1) = .Cells(i, j1)
        zakres(i, j1, 2) = .Cells(i, j1).Interior.ColorIndex
    End If
```

I hope it will help somebody :)