# To make an array of colored cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to create an array from a range of cells. The range has different colored cells. I want to pick up only the cells with a specific color, let's say green, so that the result is an array of all the green colored cells in the selected range. Kindly help me out.

Comment: We can help you with your code if you include it in your question. If you have not tried anything yet, please do that first.

Comment: Just to begin with ... Find(Ctrl+f) >> Format >> Fill >> Select Colour >> Find All << Ctrl+A to select all the cells with the selected colour. .. In vba `Debug.Print Selection.Address` ..

Comment: You can write the entire area in a dictionary. The addresses of the cells serve as keys, and the colour value for each key (each cell) is entered as a value. In the further processing of the dictionary, you can then simply check which values you need and automatically have the cells. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143375/can-vba-arrays-store-cell-properties-like-font-colors-or-fill-colors